# how to print lists of random numbers in python

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to generate and print some lists of random numbers(0 to 1) of length 1,4 and 9. For example:

```
[0.2341434134]  
[0.1314124124,0.341241234213,0.1234123412,0.12341243]  
[0.412341,0.141234,0.1412341,0.141234,0.1412341,0.1241234,0.1231243,0.134123,0.1234123]
```

This is what I've got but output is very different.

```
import random  
the_list = []

    def generateLists(j): 
        while (len(the_list) < i^2):  
            randNum = random.random()  
            the_list.append(randNum)  

        return the_list

    for i in range(1,4):  
        print(generateLists(i))  
        del the_list[:]
```

Comment: Where are you getting `i` from in `generateLists`? The only parameter you have is `j`.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the line `(len(the_list) < i^2)`. The caret in python isn't an exponent operator, it's the [xor operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). You want to do `(len(the_list) < i**2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant:

```
import random  

def generateLists(j):
    the_list = []
    for i in range(j):
        the_list += [random.random()] * (i+1)**2
    return the_list

print generateLists(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the lists with list comprehensions. Be careful of `while` and also check the exponent operator for python, it is "**", not "^"

```
import random  

def generateLists(j):
    return [random.random() for repetition in xrange(j)]
```

It is unclear from your answer, but if you are trying to grow the list as the square of `j`, modify to this:

```
 def generateLists(j):
    return [random.random() for repetition in xrange(j**2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

> generate and print some lists of random numbers(0 to 1) of length 1,4 and 9

To make a list of random numbers between 0..1 of a certain **length**:

```
def random_list(length): 
    r = []
    for i in range(length):
        r.append(random.random())
    return r
```

To call this function an print the results for 1, 4 and 9.

```
for length in (1, 4, 9):
    print random_list(length)
```

There is no need for a global **the_list** variable.

If you want a silly one line solution:

```
for n in (1,4,9): print [v() for v in [random.random] * n]
```